# Importing DXF in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, import, dxf

I'd like to import a `*.dxf`-file into GIS 3.10 LTR.

Does the DXF2Shape plugin available for this version of QGIS?

Answer (score 11):

**Option 1:** You don't need a plugin for that. You can import DXF (or DWG) in Qgis with a built in option: go to:  project >> Import/Export >> Import Layers form DWG/DXF .
Later you can export or save it as a shapefile.

more info here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html?highlight=dxf#importing-a-dxf-or-dwg-file

**Option 2:** Install the plug-in AnotherDXFImporter (https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AnotherDXF2Shape/). This plug-in let you import DXF files and save them as shapefile.

Comment: The AnotherDXFImporter works fine for me. When importing as shape, can I union the layers with a QGIS function or command afterwards?